# Dependent type indexed by a term of its own type

Tags: types, coq, dependent-type

Dependent types are types which depend on a term of a type. So I'm wondering if it is possible for a **dependent type to be indexed by a term of its own type**? What I have tried is this which

```
Parameter Obj: Type.
Parameter a: Obj.
Parameter foo: Obj -> Type. 
Parameter b : foo a.
Parameter boo : Obj -> Type.
Fail Parameter c : boo b.
```

fails since `The term "b" has type "foo a" while it is expected to have type "Obj".`. Is what I'm trying to do possible with dependent type theory and how do I implement it with Coq?

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly possible in any system that I know of. It works indirectly in Agda, but does not work in any way in Coq. In Agda, you need to wrap the index with a different type:

```agda
-- forward declaration
data A : Set
data B : A -> Set

data A where
  wrap : B -> A

data B where
  -- list your other constructors here
```

This form of indexing (called "inductive-inductive") is not yet supported by Coq.